# In GDB, how to print an object so its data members would be listed in alphabetical order?

Tags: gdb

For instance, by default it would be something like

```
(gdb) print obj
$1 = {
  elephant = 0xb7d28960 <_IO_2_1_stderr_>,
  durian = 0x0,
  eggplant = 0x809ed58 "",
  peanut = 1080,
  onion = 0x0,
  ice = 0xb7d28c20 <_IO_2_1_stdin_>,
  wheat = 0x0,
  raspberry = 0x0
}
```

How to make it become

```
(gdb) print obj
$1 = {
  durian = 0x0,
  eggplant = 0x809ed58 "",
  elephant = 0xb7d28960 <_IO_2_1_stderr_>,
  ice = 0xb7d28c20 <_IO_2_1_stdin_>,
  onion = 0x0,
  peanut = 1080,
  raspberry = 0x0,
  wheat = 0x0
}
```

That is, the data members are listed in alphabetical order.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this that is built in to gdb.

If you really need to do this you could write some Python code that prints objects however you like.  You can either write a new command that works like `print`, or you could write a pretty-printer that recognizes structures and sorts the members.

That said, there are two reasons to keep things the way they are.  First, the current order mirrors what is actually written in your source.  Second, the current order also shows the layout in memory of the object.  Both of these things help reduce confusion.